# Override class variables within a loop

Tags: python, class, object

Assuming I have a class which is defined with variables as follows:

```
import numpy as np
class DataShell:
    dS=''
    name=''
    type=''
    some other variables
```

I initialize an object

```
Obj=DataShell()
```

I have a dictionary L and I want to assign the values from the dictionary to the class variables of the object

```
{'name': 'abc', 'type': 'def', 'dS': 'hij'}
```

I am trying out the following code to do this:

```
attributes = [attr for attr in dir(Obj) 
              if not attr.startswith('__')]
for key in L:
    for el in attributes:
        if key==el:
            Obj.el=str(L[key])
```

This is creating a new variable in my object called `'el'` and assigning a value to it instead of changing my `Obj.name`, `Obj.dS` or `Obj.type`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setattr` and `hasattr`. For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    attr1 = 1
    attr2 = 2

myobject = MyClass()

m = {'attr1': 19, 'some_other_name': 'blah'}
for name, value in m.items():
    if hasattr(myobject, name):
        setattr(myobject, name, value)

print(myobject.attr1)  # 19
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not make an initialization function that takes the values?

```
class DataShell:
    def __init__(self, dS='', name='', type=''):
        dS = dS
        name = name
        type = type
```

Then use:

```
DataShell(**L)
```

Or even easier in Python 3 use `dataclass`

```
import dataclass 

@dataclass
class DataShell:
    dS: str  = ''
    name: str  = ''
    type: str  = ''

Obj = DataShell(**L)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you copied in the question is not at all working. I tried to modify your code and now it is working -

```
class DataShell:
    dS=''
    name=''
    type=''

Obj=DataShell()
print(id(Obj))
L = {'name': 'abc', 'type': 'def', 'dS': 'hij'}
attributes = [attr for attr in dir(Obj) 
              if not attr.startswith('__')]
print(attributes)
for key in L:
    for el in attributes:
        if key==el:
            if hasattr(Obj, el):
                setattr(Obj, el, L[key]) 

print(id(Obj))
print(dir(Obj))
print(Obj.dS)
print(Obj.name)
print(Obj.type)
```

use `setattr` for dynamically setting the class attributes